# REST call works with curl, fails with python

Tags: python, rest, curl

I know there are some similar questions on here but I haven't been able to find a solution that works for me. I have the following curl request that works from Command Prompt:

```
curl -G -d api_token=[TOKEN1] -d access_token=[TOKEN2] https://api.indiegogo.com/2/accounts/[PAGE_ID]/contributions.json
```

But when I translate it into the following python code, it returns a 404 error.

```
 data = {
  'api_token':'[TOKEN1]',
  'access_token':'[TOKEN2]'
 }

response = requests.post('https://api.indiegogo.com/2/accounts/[ID]/contributions.json', data=data)
```

I think it might have something to do with the headers, but I have played around with it and can't figure out how to make it work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [API documentation](http://developer.indiegogo.com/docs/campaign-contributions), you need to pass `api_token` and `access_token` as query string to api using [`params`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls) parameter.

```
data = {
  'api_token':'[TOKEN1]',
  'access_token':'[TOKEN2]'
 }

response = requests.get('https://api.indiegogo.com/2/accounts/[ID]/contributions.json', params=data)
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek, but this did not solve the problem. I am still getting a 404 error. Any other ideas?

Comment: Actually this did fix it, but I also needed to change to a requests.get.

Comment: yeah updated answer based on that, 404 means either `ID` you're passing is wrong or call you're doing is not possible